# string copy() function return misunderstood? (C)

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, strcpy, function-definition

(EDIT)

Probable misunderstanding in updating and returning a string from a function in C.

I'm a student and have just started trying out dynamic memory allocation techniques. Recently, I was told to work on a string copy() function similar to the strcpy() function in C under <string.h>.

It is supposed to be taking two arguments: char c1[],char c2[].
**Momentarily, I am focusing on a constraint wherein the length of string c1 is lesser than the string c2**. This is the case, we will be copying a larger string into a smaller one. So, naturally it would have to expand the former string's size. *(I have defined a function len() which returns the length of the string. It's working fine)*

Code:

```
char* copy(char c1[],char c2[])
{
    int i=0;
    int lc1=len(c1);
    int lc2=len(c2);
    if(lc1<lc2)
    {
                //are the following two lines allowed?
        c1=(char*) malloc(lc1*sizeof(char));
        c1=(char*) realloc(c1,lc2*sizeof(char));
        for(i=0;i<lc2;i++)
        {
            *(c1+i)=c2[i];
        }
        *(c1+lc2)='\0';
    }
    return c1;
}
```

*I won't be surprised if this code has multiple issues!
*
I tried testing it as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mystring.h"
main()
{
    int i;
    char s1[12],s2[12];
    gets(s1);
    gets(s2);
    printf("copy: %s",copy(s1,s2));
    printf("\ns1: %s",s1);
}
```

I got:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpoZn.png)

I wanted both of the outputs to be the same, i.e. copy's and s1's. It happens to be that only this functions only when I print it along with the invokation. I was expecting it to print the copy when I printed s1.

Where have I gone wrong? I think it's something related to the scope of the variables I'm dealing with, or the pointers and memory allocation as a whole!

**EDIT:**
I had made an alternative-function xcopy:

```
char* xcopy(char c1[])
{
    int i=0;
    int lc1=len(c1);
    char* c2=(char*) malloc((lc1+1)*sizeof(char));
    for(i=0;i<lc1;i++)
    {
        *(c2+i)=c1[i];
    }
    *(c2+lc1)='\0';
    return c2;
}
```

**I realised this function was not solving the actual problem.**

---

Thankyou for your help!!

Comment: Your function `copy`  doesn't modify the contents of the array `s1`.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Thanks, I realised!

Comment: `gets()` has been removed completely from C standard: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `copy` does not make sense.

For starters it is not necessary that the array pointed to by the parameter `c1` contains a string. So this line

```
int lc1=len(c1);
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Even if the array pointed to by the pointer `c1` contains a string the stored string can be much lesser than the size of the array. So again this line

```
int lc1=len(c1);
```

with the following if statement

```
if(lc1<lc2)
```

does not make sense.

Also allocating memory two times

```
c1=(char*) malloc(lc1*sizeof(char));
c1=(char*) realloc(c1,lc2*sizeof(char));
```

is unsafe, redundant and inefficient.

Actually the function does not copy the string pointed to by the pointer `c2` in the destination array. Thus using the parameter `c1` again does not make sense. Your function looks like POSIX function `strdup` if to remove the first senseless parameter.

You did not show how the function `len` that calculates length of a string but it seems it does not count the terminating zero character of a string. In this case you need at least to allocate memory using the expression `( lc2 + 1 ) * sizeof( char )` to reserve memory for the terminating zero character `'\0'`. Otherwise this statement

```
*(c1+lc2)='\0';
```

invokes undefined behavior.

It is the responsibility of the user of the function to provide a destination array large enough to store the source string. The function shall not allocate any memory.

By analogy with the standard C function `strcpy` the function can look the following way

```
char * copy( char s1[], const char s2[] )
{
    for ( char *p = s1; ( *p++ = *s2++ ) != '\0'; );

    return s1;
}
```

Pay attention to that the function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead use standard C function `fgets`. It can append a string with the new line character `'\n'`.

To remove it you can write for example

```
c2[ strcspn( c2, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Comment: The if() is unnecessary, I did realise, but it was part of a more expansive function i had made earlier. I just copied the segment including it, i did realise it was meaningless.Function len() did count the terminating character, I just messed up the +1 in the allocation process. Thanks for the insight and your answer !! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* headers.h
#define SLEN 100
#define SLENT 200

typedef struct size {
    size_t length_one[SLEN];
    size_t length_two[SLENT];

} siz, *siz_point;

char * copy(char var1[], char var2[])
{
    struct size siz;
    int i = 0;

    siz.length_one = strlen(var1);
    siz.length_two = strlen(var2);

    if (siz.length_one < siz.length_two) {

        void vars_one = (char *) malloc(siz.length_one * sizeof(siz.length_one));
        void vars_two = (char *) memcpy(siz.length_one, siz.length_two, size_t memory);

        for (i=0; i < siz.length_two; i++) {
            *(var1+i) = var2[i];
        }
        *(var1 + siz.length_two) = '\0';
    }
    return var1;
}


*/

#define LEN 20

char * s_gets(char * set_string, size_t isize_n);

char * s_gets(char * set_string, size_t isize_n) {
    char * retnval;
    char * findval;

    retnval = fgets(set_string, isize_n, stdin);
    if (retnval) {
        findval = strchr(set_string, '\n');
        if (findval) *findval = '\0';
        else
            while (getchar() != '\n')
                continue;
    }
    return retnval;
}

int
main() {

    int i;
    char string_one[LEN];
    char string_two[LEN];

    s_gets(string_one, "This string one");
    s_gets(string_two, "This string two");

    printf("Copying string: %s", copy(string_one, string_two));
    printf("\nString: %s", string_one);
}
```

maybe your code looks like this

Comment: Rather than just posting code, you should consider adding some explanation to your answer, and detail how it addresses the OP's problem(s).

Comment: sure, ... at above 'void xcopy function' need to copying string with new placeholder so that's the function automatic copying, with creating new function of 'memcpy()' i think the authors want to creating new function likes memcpy for copying from older memory to new memory and want to exchange them, for 'gets() function' i used new 'gets() function' with size checker, for avoiding buffer overflows, gets(string_one) unknown the size there's just copying the string without knowing exact size @AdrianMole

Comment: so at the end the copy function can exchange the value like string_one  = "This string two" and string_two = "This string one"